# Question about the categories in the Critique of Pure Reason

Tags: kant

For the past couple of weeks I have been reading Critique of Pure Reason by Immanuel Kant. Currently I am stuck at the chapter on transcendental deduction of the categories (Version B). So far my own personal interpretation is that:

1.Original apperception is some primordial sense of self which cannot be grasped because it produces representation "I think" which helps us to grasp everything else.

2."I think" accompanies all given representation result is unity of apperception which gives us information on the number of representations in our mind.

3.Synthetic unity of apperception is a particular instance of unity of apperception i.e. it is synthesis of intuitively given manifold.

4.Product of synthesis is concept. Product of pure synthesis is category.

5.Pure synthesis is combination of the manifold of time itself. This manifold is given a priori. Keeping in mind what Kant wrote in transcendental aesthetics I presume this means that "I think" can be attributed to the combination of different sequences of time in the backdrop of unified form of inner sense.

6.Result of a pure synthesis is a pure concept of a certain degree of reality and unity on which we can base empirical concepts (sun appears as 10 000 moonlights)

7.Pure concepts act as basis for empirical ones which can be used in judgments to unite many representations under one ( All bodies are divisible. General concept of divisibility related to body which relates to some appearance.).

First of all, do these 7 points make any sense? Personally I don't like it because I seem to ignore the role of interpretation in all of this. But what do you think? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is not what is meant by "personal philosophy", as it is a question on a defined philosophical text with a limited amount of informed propositions that can be measured against it, not mere opinions or statements. The question clearly *is* answerable, the close vote not justified imho.

Comment: Hi, welcome to philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see how to craft questions better. Your question currently asks about too many different things for one post, and most of them are not even about categories but about the transcendental unity of apperception and synthesis. But for what it is worth, concepts and categories to Kant are not products but rather acts or functions that bring multiplicity of sensations to unity. Categories are the most basic concepts, and they do serve as templates for empirical ones on some interpretations.

Comment: Regarding the question itself, please elaborate on what you mean by 'the role of interpretation' if you need this to be adressed, but this should be asked in a seperate question anyways. I read this as mainly a question on how apperception (pure and empirical), pure synthesis (categories) and synthesis (imho *things/representations*, not concepts) are intertwined and characterised. This should be made clear as well. Last but not least, do not ask for thoughts, ask for objective, referenced answers, as this is what SE is all about ;)